# Email 'email_calendar' not found in CalendarMailerPreview Rails Mailer Preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I've created a basic mailer and am not able to see the preview using the following path: http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/calendar_mailer/calendar_email

Here is my mailer, preview, and email body code:

calendar_mailer.rb:

```
class CalendarMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "notifications@cogsmart.com"

  def calendar_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Your Cogsmart To Do List')
  end
end
```

calendar_mailer_preview.rb:

```
class CalendarMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview

  def calendar_email
    CalendarMailer.calendar_email(User.first)
  end

end
```

calendar_email.html.erb:

```
<h1>Thanks @user.name for using Cogsmart, here's your calendar</h1>
```

Comment: where did you put the preview code?

Comment: in mailers/previews folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.6/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html)
The preview needs to go in the **test**/mailers/previews folder